# Using earth as a conductor

Tags: electric-circuits, conductors, earth

[image]

"To use the earth as a conductor, you can't merely stick a little wire into the ground next to the tomato plants. You have to use something that maintains substantial contact with the earth, and by that, I mean a conductor with a large surface area. One good solution is a copper pole at least 8 feet long and ½ inch in diameter. That provides 150 square inches of contact with the Earth. You can bury the pole into the ground with a sledgehammer and then connect a wire to it. Or, if the cold-water pipes in your home are made of copper and originate in the ground outside the house, you can connect a wire to the pipe." [Charles Petzold, Code - The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software]

I did not understand why we need a "substantial contact" to make the circuit work. If Earth is not a good conductor does it matter if we use a big contact or not? How does it change anything?

Comment: yes it does, the resistance decreases with area in the denominator

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent After your comment, I searched a bit more and some things got clicked, thanks. But I have one more question: would it work if I put both ends into the Earth so that both ends are very close to each other?

Comment: If they are very close, what is the point of using the Earth as a conductor? It would waste the copper hammered into the ground when you can just touch them and get far better results.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I am asking to find out whether it works or not.

Comment: If the long distance one works, then it must work for short distance too.

Comment: You cannot put both ends of the battery into the Earth, though.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent It does not work if I do not use a pole for long distances, but I think it will work without using extra stuff for short distances. Thanks.

Comment: If you mean with both ends, both ends of the batterie  it does not work, it would be a shortcut to the batterie, and empty it. and your bulb could not work. it is almost the same as putting both ends directly together.

Comment: Please do not quote without naming the source.

Comment: Thank you for editing to include the source.  Now unless you are Charles Petzold, please do not describe that source as "my book".  If you are trying to convey the information that you own a copy of that book, then you should say so unambiguously --- but only after stopping to ask yourself why anybody would need to know that in order to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a passage from my book. I did not understand why we need a
> "substantial contact" to make the circuit work. If Earth is not a good
> conductor does it matter if we use a big contact or not? How does it
> change anything?

A lower resistance 'earthing rod' causes the 'ground voltage' to be less of a function of the current flowing to ground. Although the ground itself will still have resistance, the grounding circuit will be closer to the ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In general electrical circuits involve some different parts, such as wires, voltage source, load (e.g. light bulb, motor, greenhouse heater), switch and so on. Where one part,  such as a wire, connects to another part, such as load or simply another wire, you have a contact.

In a printed circuit these contacts are often made using solder. Solder is highly conducting and bonds with e.g. copper or gold making a very good contact where there is almost no resistance. Another way to make a good contact is to screw a screw down tightly against a bunch of copper threads in a wire, pushing them against another piece of metal. This is often done in household circuits.
But in principle no such contact is completely perfect; they all offer a bit of electrical resistance.

In the case of contact with the soil you don't have the highly conducting bond as you get with solder, nor the high pressure forcing surfaces together as with a screw. You only have pressure of the surrounding soil pushing the soil against your metal wire or pin, and the moisture. Although water (with impurities) conducts (at low frequency) reasonably well, it is nowhere near as good a conductor as copper. So to compensate for this you want a large cross-sectional area of soil conducting your current, which brings the resistance down. To allow there to be a large cross-sectional area right from your metal pin or wire, you should make the wire or pin itself have a high surface area in contact with the soil. That's what the book is recommending.